# Check file upload during ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have form where other elements along with file upload.For file upload I used

`<form method="post" id="add_charges" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

In the ajaxRequest I used

```
var formData = new Formdata('#add-charges')[0];

$.ajax({
        url: 'function/ajax/topup.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
});
```

In a PHP after posting the form if I checked for $_FILES array it gives me a blank array since I have not uploaded the file. Is there any way to check file upload size before that data send through ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I think in ajax request you must set Content-type for upload files. try this :

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'function/ajax/topup.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false
});
```

And maybe you should serialize data from.

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'function/ajax/topup.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#add-charges').serialize(),
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false
    });
```

Hope helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax send file and PHP check $_FILES.

```
 var sofg_mixup = jQuery.noConflict();
    sofg_mixup(document).ready(function() {
        sofg_mixup('#ct-file').change(function() {
            var fileInput = sofg_mixup('#ct-file').prop('files')[0];
            var myFormData = new FormData();
            myFormData.append('ct_file', fileInput);
            sofg_mixup.ajax({
                url: 'save_file.php',
                type: 'POST',
                processData: false, // important
                contentType: false, // important
                dataType: 'json',
                data: myFormData,
                success: function(jsonData) {
                    console.log(jsonData);
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(xhr);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```